# Agile Toolkit 4.2.4 is not working in development server

Tags: php, atk4, agiletoolkit

Respected Sir/Madam,
  I am new in Agile Toolkit, a PHP Framework. I have downloaded from http://agiletoolkit.org/distfiles/agiletoolkit-4.2.4.zip and then I have uploaded on the ftp server and changed the permission of all files as well as directories of Agil Toolkit with 777. It is not working in development server(ftp server). It shows an Internal Server Error. And another thing I don't have any access in cPanel.
But same thing, I have installed in local server, xampp/htdocs, it works fine.What are the reasons. Why it shows internal server error. To make it work, what I will have to do. If any one knows about this type issue, Please reply me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

0777 - this is the reason. Usually live servers will not let you execute any php file with 0777 because it might be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 0777 i.e permission is the main reason. After uploading the files and directories in ftp server, it is not needed to change the permission. If the permission has been changed, Internal server error would be showed. So it is not needed to change the permission. Thank You